# How do I format each cell in column FOO in Excel if the len() of the cell value is longer then BAR?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

If this is the wrong place to ask this let me know.

Here is the formula I have right now:

```
=LEN($A$2)>$AB$11
```

Applies to:

```
=$A$2
```

That works great for the one cell. I need it to apply to each cell in the column.

If it was C# I would do something like this:

```
foreach(cell in columnA)
{
   if(cell.text.length > (INT)$AB$11.text)
   {
      cell.format(red)
   }
}
```

In other words how do I format each cell in column FOO if the len() of the cell value is longer then BAR?

Comment: This looks like something for stackoverflow, if you ask me...

Comment: Yeah I don't know. If I found this question on SO I would say it belongs somewhere else. Where I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to generate the formatting programmatically for a large number of cells, you can do it with a macro (VBA), but if you're just looking for a quick and easy solution, you can drop the $'s from your original formula and copy and paste.  In other words:

> =LEN(A2)>$AB$11

Applies to A2, but if you copy and paste that into, say, B3, from B2 (that is to say, one cell down from the original), it will update itself to be this:

> =LEN(A3)>$AB$11

You can paste across a large range of cells and it will update all of them.  References without dollar signs are relative references, and will be updated in a copy/paste; references with dollar signs are absolute.  I'm presuming, by the way, that AB11 holds a certain parameter you want to compare all cells to.  If you're comparing them all to the single value, leave the dollar signs in that reference.  If you're comparing a column to another column, relative references can do that for you too like this:

> =LEN(A2)>$AB11

Comment: Gotcha. Here is what is odd... Formula: =LEN(A2)>$AB$11    Applies to: =$A$2:$A$88       Does exactly what I need. I'm just not sure how. There is some odd automagic going on here.